# Expression<Func<TEntity, int, bool> set the int value

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, func

I have this Expression

```
 public Expression<Func<TEntity, int, bool>> FilterExpr
```

And Now I want to eliminate/insert the value for the int value

like

```
int i = 12;
//Pseudo Code which sets the value of the second Parameter
FilterExpr.Arg2 = i;
```

the result should be a

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>
```

without the int parameter

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new expression by replacing parameter in the body and creating new lambda expression with one parameter. For example using this replacer (or take [`ReplacingExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.replacingexpressionvisitor?view=efcore-5.0) if you are using EF Core 3.0+):

```cs
public static class ExpressionExt
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacingVisitor { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

And modify expression:

```cs
var withReplaced = FilterExpr.Body.ReplaceParameter(
    FilterExpr.Parameters[1], // replace second parameter 
    Expression.Constant(42)); // with some constant
// build new expression with only one parameter by reusing first parameter of original one
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>(withReplaced, FilterExpr.Parameters[0]);
```